# How to make WhatsApp store media on external SD card (instead of device storage)?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, whatsapp-messenger, 5.1-lollipop, media-files

I have a lot of media files circulating between all my contacts and groups in **WhatsApp**. And all the media (images, audio, video) takes a lot of space on the device storage (internal). I have not found a way to change default storage path from internal memory to **external SD** card. Is it somehow possible for a user of no great expertise in Android to adjust it so that all the media will be automatically sent to SD card (smth like: `sdcard/WhatsApp/Media/` ).

---

I have tried to manually create the following folder on SD card:

```
sdcard/WhatsApp/Media/
```

But anyway the messenger does not see it and it creates new folders on the device storage (inspite of my removing the folder on device storage).

Comment: Sorry, but that behaviour seems to be hardcoded into WhatsApp itself. If no one of the others have a better solution, the only way is to periodically move the folders yourself, or write a script to do so for you.

Comment: Use the FolderMount app to create a symlink.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is no way you can do this without **root access**. If you know what is **rooting** or if you have already rooted your mobile, then follow this answer. But if you don't know, please don't consider this answer. Rooting may cause potential problem to your device if you don't know what you are doing.

1. **FolderMount**: FolderMount is an app which creates a symlink to your sdcard or anyother directory when you specify.
2. **XInternal2SD** (Xposed Module): it is an xposed module in which you can specify internal storage path. For me, I have 32gb class 10 card, so I set my card my internal using this module. So whenever I newly install an app, it will be automatically installed to my SD card. So the media files downloaded are directly download to my SD card. There are several xposed module which does the same, but I'm using this module, cause I'm comfortable with it.
3. **Link2SD**: Using Link2SD you can partition your SD card and use it as internal. If you do this, it will work as same as XInternal2SD xposed module. There are plenty of tutorials available on internet on how to use link2sd.

---

Again I'm warning you. If you don't know what is **rooting**, don't follow this answer.

Comment: have you actually tried these?  foldermount did not work with whatsapp when I tried it

Comment: Yeah the bind mount in Apps2SD to FAT32 SD card doesn't work either.  It sees old images but new ones get lost somehow.

Comment: No I didn't folder mount.. I've heard from friends.. but perhaps I've got xinternal2sd.. I'm using it for almost over a year..